# How to use Angular Date-picker in Json format Year DD/MM/YYYY only?

Tags: json, angular, date, datetime, datepicker

I am trying to use Date-picker in a reactive form. Also, implemented MomentDateAdapter to customize:

```js
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: ['YYYY-MM-DD'],
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'L',
    monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'L',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
  },
};
```

In a form I have date input. So far so good:

[image]

But in JSON object from the reactive form I Have this date format value:
[image]

When I need to be in this 'YYYY-MM-DD' format only. Not datetime format!

Any help, I appreciate it.

Comment: For interoperability, the JSON standard defines a specific format to use for date/time values. If you want a real date/time value, rather than a string, this is what you should expect. The server code will be able to read this in the correct way, including the time zone, as a date/time value, and then if you only care about the date with no time you can extract it **at that level on the server**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to convert the date by a custom function:

```
export function formatDate(date: Date): string {
    if (isNaN(date.getTime())) {
        return '';
    } else {
        const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        const day = date.getDate();
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        return ('00' + month).slice(-2) + '/' + ('00' + day).slice(-2) + '/' + year; //You can define your format here.
    }
}
```

Now use this function while you are saving the object:

```
formatDate(dueDate)
```